can a node create two different BOLT12 offers with the same description?
Core Lightning does not seem to allow creating of two offers with the same description. At first, I thought this might be a bug. However, after looking at BOLT12, the only other unique field I see besides offer_description is offer_metadata. offer_issuer_id and/or offer_paths seem like they should be common across offers (at least offer_paths should stay the same until your path changes).
Core Lightning does not allow setting the offer_metadata field (https://docs.corelightning.org/reference/lightning-offer) when creating an offer. Also, phoenixd is even more constrained in that it only allows setting a single offer (https://phoenix.acinq.co/server/api#get-bolt12-offer) per node.
Are there any examples of how offer_metadata should be structured by an offer writer and how it should be interpreted by the offer reader? How much flexibility do we have on the data that goes in there? Is this the best field to use to make multiple unique offers with the same offer_description?
